# Landmark localization using CNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to perform landmark localization on images using CNN in Keras.

I have 800 images and I resize them in 320x240 and normalize them between 0 and 1. My annotation are in a XML file and I put them into a CSV file and then create a .npy file for images and annotation.

I use Adam optimizer with `learning rate = 0.001`. Loss is a `custom rmse` and metrics is `mae`.

```
# RMSE
from keras import backend
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

I've tried `batch size = 32, 50, 60, 70`. Activation function is `relu` except for nothing in the last Dense layer because it is a regression problem.

This is my CNN architecture:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 240, 320, 32)      320       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 240, 320, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 120, 160, 32)      9248      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 120, 160, 32)      128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 60, 80, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 60, 80, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 40, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 30, 40, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 20, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 15, 20, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 10, 64)         36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 8, 10, 64)         256       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 5120)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               2621952
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 136)               34952
```

There aren't Pooling layer because image size are reduced by `strides = 2` in conv layer.

136 are my x,y coordinates output.

The result is always similar to this and I stop learning after 25-30 epochs because val_loss remains stable around 44:

```
Train on 661 samples, validate on 166 samples

Epoch 1/500
 - 71s - loss: 139.1782 - mae: 135.1071 - val_loss: 157.1107 - val_mae: 154.2357
Epoch 2/500
 - 72s - loss: 52.8662 - mae: 43.3649 - val_loss: 157.6703 - val_mae: 154.7970
Epoch 3/500
 - 68s - loss: 31.2599 - mae: 24.8241 - val_loss: 157.5264 - val_mae: 154.6493
Epoch 4/500
 - 68s - loss: 26.4959 - mae: 20.9077 - val_loss: 157.2360 - val_mae: 154.3627
Epoch 5/500
 - 69s - loss: 23.6135 - mae: 18.6571 - val_loss: 157.1423 - val_mae: 154.2634
Epoch 6/500
 - 69s - loss: 22.0984 - mae: 17.4924 - val_loss: 157.0344 - val_mae: 154.1478
Epoch 7/500
 - 68s - loss: 20.1804 - mae: 16.0166 - val_loss: 156.7843 - val_mae: 153.9042
Epoch 8/500
```

I assume that the model is in overfitting. I've tried also adding a Dropout layer after the first two Dense layer but the result is still the same.

How can I improve my model?

Comment: Are you doing Data Augmentation (smalls random change on images so that the dataset is a little more diversified).
You can aslo try to change other hyperparamters than just batch size (lr ...).
You could luse firsts layers from a pretrained network.
You could also try to improve your dataset size

Comment: No, I didn't do Data Augmentation because I have no idea how to perform it with point coordinates. And I didn't change other hyperparameters (only batch size, and loss function - I used also MSE but it was very very high). And where I can find a pretrained network?

Comment: If you're annotation are just coordinates you can crop a subpart of the image and adapt the annotation to match the new crop, you can also flip or rotate the images while doing the same with annotation, with randomness during preprocessing

Comment: Nevertheless do you think that to improve my model is necessary only to increase dataset size?